# How to split characters with "-" character?

Tags: php, function, split

I generated a serial number with php, the length of this serial number is 16 characters, I want to split this serial number in 4 characters with dash(-) character, like this format xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx so I wrote this php code:

```
for ($d=0; $d<=3; $d++){
     $tmp .= ($tmp ? "-" : null).substr($serial,$d,4);
}
```

so this loop will return a serial number with xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx format,

I want to know is there any better way or function in php?

I searched in internet I found `sprintf` and `number_format` but I don't know how can I use this function for this format !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$result = implode( '-', str_split( $serial, 4));
```

`str_split()` will break the string into an array, where each element has 4 characters. Then, `implode()` joins those array pieces together with a dash.

So, if we generate a random `$serial` with:

```
$serial = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 16);
```

We would get [as output](http://viper-7.com/Q3HOQ4) something similar to:

```
59e6-997f-8446-80a2
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
$str   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
echo substr(chunk_split($str, 4, '-'), 0, -1);
```

Output :

```
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

Comment: do you really need that substr() call there?

Comment: Yes , or there will be `-` at the end

Comment: +1 this is actually the fastest method, since no intermediate array is created. Using chunk_split is around 40% faster than str_split, measured over 100000 iterations and a 16 char string.

Answer (score 1):

## str_split, fairly clear...

```
$hyphenated = implode( '-', str_split( $str, 4));
```

That is pretty clear, but it seems kind of wasteful to generate an array only to implode it. So I wondered if there was another way...

## Faster with preg_replace?

I tried a regex, thinking that would eliminate the need for an intermediate array. After all, why have one problem, when you can have [two](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)!

```
$hyphenated = preg_replace('/(.{4})(?=.)/', '$1-', $str);
```

That little beastie looks for 4 characters, and as long they are followed by at least one more character, will insert a slash after them.

Trouble is, it turned out to be around 25% slower :(

## chunk_split faster and with the same great minty taste!

Prasanth Bendra posted a pretty efficient answer which needs no intermediate array

```
$hyphenated=substr(chunk_split($str, 4, '-'), 0, -1);
```

Result! This was at least 25% faster than using str_split measured on a 16 character input string, and just as clear as the str_split method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) with an [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) such as:

```
$tmpArray = str_split($tmp, 4);
$serialNumber = implode('-', $tmpArray);
```